# Fragmentar string em partes aleatorias

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um script em JS que fragmente qualquer string em partes aleatórias, digamos que tenho uma string:

```
x = "Deliciosogostoeobomgostodasnuvensseremfeitasdealgodao"
```

e após inserida no script, ela possa ser retornada assim por exemplo:

```
"Del icios ogos t oeobo mgosto das nuvensser emf eitasde a lgod ao"
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Se sim, coloque o código, explique-o e descreva quais os problemas encontrados.

Comment: achei um código e alterei ele mas ele não separa direito, sempre fica faltando alguma letra
`var str = 'Deliciosogostoeobomgostodasnuvensseremfeitasdealgodao';
var chunks = [];

for (var i = 0, charsLength = str.length; i < charsLength; i += (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)) {
    chunks.push(str.substring(i, i + (Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1)));
}
console.log(chunks.toString().replace(/\,/g," "));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue isso quebrando a string em partes de no máximo 9 caracteres (isso você pode mudar no código onde tem `9`) e adicionando à uma array e depois juntando tudo com `join`:

**Exemplo:**

```js
var x = "Deliciosogostoeobomgostodasnuvensseremfeitasdealgodao",
    x_novo = [];
while(x.length > 0){
   var rn1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1,
       parte = x.substring( x.charAt(0), rn1 );
   x_novo.push(parte);
   x = x.replace(parte,'');
}

x_novo = x_novo.join(" ");
console.log(x_novo);
```

**Exemplo sem usar array:**

```js
var x = "Deliciosogostoeobomgostodasnuvensseremfeitasdealgodao",
    x_novo = '';
while(x.length > 0){
   var rn1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1,
   parte = x.substring(x.charAt(0), rn1);
   x_novo += (x_novo.length > 0 ? ' ' : '')+parte;
   x = x.replace(parte, '');
}

console.log(x_novo);
```

Comment: Tenho uma ligeira discordância quanto ao jeito como `pedaco` (na segunda parte, não na primeira) foi removido da string original. Tenho ressalvas quanto ao fato de que o `replace` possa pegar uma substring idêntica ao pedaço mas que ocorra antes dele, podendo então não gerar hipotéticas substrings que poderiam ser geradas caso fosse arrancado o pedaço adequado. Mas, enfim, ressalvas apenas, não fui atrás de validar minha preocupação, nem essa preocupação purista deveria retirar o mérito da resposta

Comment: Vc tem razão. Não pensei nessa possibilidade. Vou analisar isso. Até porque a segunda resposta não faz nem parte da pergunta, coloquei só de bônus mesmo. Realmente pode dar diferença.

Answer (score 3):

Criei uma função que faz este trabalho, entretanto, te aconselho a testar e otimizar ela antes de aplicar em um caso real, ainda mais quando a string for muito grande. Eu faria isto no server-side e mandava a string processada para o client-side.

Veja:

```
function dividirStrPor(str, caractereDivisao, pedacos)
{
  var tam = str.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < pedacos; i++)
  {
    posicao = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tam - 0 + 1) + 0);

    str = str.slice(0, posicao) + caractereDivisao + str.slice(posicao);
  }

  return str;
}


var str = "Deliciosogostoeobomgostodasnuvensseremfeitasdealgodao";

var resultado = dividirStrPor(str, " ", 12);

console.log(resultado);
```

Saída:

> D e lic iosogos  t oeob omgostodas nuvensseremfe i  t asdealgodao

A saída muda a cada chamada da função, devida a posição aleatória na qual o caractere de divisão será inserido na string.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/InsignificantJadedHexagons).

Fontes:

[JavaScript: How can I insert a string at a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)
[Generate random number between two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975/generate-random-number-between-two-numbers-in-javascript)